# JmsOutboundGateway how can we set alter replyTo when sending out bound message so it is not same as replyDestination?

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We have a MQ request/reply pattern implementation

[image]

Here we use a IBM MQ Cluster host. Here the request/reply queues on both sides are linked to each other by the MQ cluster environment, as the queue managers of different systems within the cluster talks to each other.

Our Requestor code uses Spring JMS Integration - JmsOutboundGateway  to send and receive message
The service provider is a Mainframe application which we have no control.

```
    public class JmsOutboundGatewayConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboundRequestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel outboundResponseChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundRequestChannel")
    public JmsOutboundGateway jmsTestOutboundGateway(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsOutboundGateway gateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        gateway.setRequestDestinationName("REQUEST.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE");
        gateway.setReplyDestinationName("REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE");
        gateway.setReplyChannel(outboundResponseChannel());
        gateway.setRequiresReply(true);
        return gateway;
    }
}
```

```
// Requestor - sendAndReceive code
outboundRequestChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("payload"));
Message<?> response = outboundResponseChannel.receive(10000);
```

**Issue:**
The issue we are facing when we send message, the gateway code is also passing the **replyTo** = queue://REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE.
Now the mainframe program that consumes this message , it is forced to reply back to the replyTo queue. It is failing on mainframe side as this replyTo queue which we send is not part of their MQ Mgr/env.

I could not find a way to remove the **replyTo** when sending message. As JmsOutboundGateway set this replyTo using the "ReplyDestinationName" which I had configured.
Our requestor will need to set the "ReplyDestinationName" as we are listening to this Alias-cluster reply queue for reply back.

I looked at the Channel interceptor options, I could only Intercept the message to alter it, but no option to change the **replyTo**.

- Is there way to alter the **replyTo** i.e  replyTo and ReplyDestination different?
- Is there anyway to remove/not-set the **replyTo** when sending message to request queue?

Just wondering how to get this working for such MQ cluster environment where the **replyTo** queue will have to kept what the mainframe consumer service want, that is different to the **replyDestination** queue which we use.
Considering that the **replyTo** is used by the mainframe service to reply back. If it is not passed the mainframe service will use its own reply queue which is linked to our reply-cluster-alias queue.

Any inputs appreciated?

Thanks
Saishm

**Further clarification**:
The cluster mq env we have,  Our spring jms outbound gateway is writing request to - "REQUEST.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE"   & listening to the reply on "REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE"
So the jmsOutboundGateway sets the replyTo=REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE

Now the mainframe service on the other side is reading the message from "REQUEST.LOCAL.QUEUE". In the cluster env the "REQUEST.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE" ands its QMGR are linked to "REQUEST.LOCAL.QUEUE" and its QMGR, this is all managed within the cluster MQ env.

The mainframe service when consuming the request, sees that the incoming message had a replyTo and tries to send the response to this replyTo.
The issue is mainframe was supposed to reply to "REPLY.LOCAL.QUEUE" which is linked to REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE
If there is no replyTo it would have send the reply to "REPLY.LOCAL.QUEUE".

Now from the jmsOutBoundGateway I dont have any options to remove replyTo when sending mEssage or edit it to "REPLY.LOCAL.QUEUE" and keep listening to the response/reply of the request on "REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE"

Comment: Not sure if I understand your environment properly, but did you look at [Configuring request/reply to a cluster](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=clusters-configuring-requestreply-cluster)?

Comment: @DanielSteinmann, I have added further clarification on our MQ cluster env. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like a `JmsOutboundGateway` will fit your IBM MQ cluster configuration and requirements. You just cannot use that `replyTo` feature since we cannot bypass JMS protocol over here.

Consider to use a pair of `JmsSendingMessageHandler` and `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` components, respectively. Your `JmsSendingMessageHandler` will just send a JMS message to the `REQUEST.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE` and forget. Only what you need is to supply a `JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID`. The `JmsHeaderMapper` will populate a `jmsMessage.setJMSCorrelationID()` property - the same way as `JmsOutboundGateway` does that by default. In this case your mainframe service is free to use its own reply queue and I guess it will supply our `correlationId` correctly.

A `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` has to be subscribed to the `REPLY.ALIAS.CLUSTER.QUEUE` and you do a correlation between request and reply yourself. For example a `Map` of `correlationId` and `Future` to fulfill when reply comes back.